# How to use jq to convert this string to JSON?

Tags: json, bash, shell, parsing, jq

How can I use jq to convert the following lines to a JSON format?

```
payment_test_service1_api[host] HOST1
payment_test_service1_api[username] USERNAME1
payment_test_service1_api[password] PASSWORD1
```

To this JSON format:

```
"payment_test" {
    "service1" : 
    {
      "api": {
        "host": "HOST1",
        "username": "USERNAME1",
        "password": "PASSWORD1"
      }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

The following is more general than @chepner's solution (it uses `add` and therefore is not restricted to three key-value pairs) and perhaps slightly simpler:

```
$ jq -Rn 'inputs | match("\\[(.*)\\] (.*)")
    | .captures | {(.[0].string): (.[1].string)} ' tmp.txt |
  jq -s '{payment_test: { service1: { api: add }}} '
```

Now it's easy to see how to eliminate the second call to jq:

```
jq -Rn '[ inputs | match("\\[(.*)\\] (.*)")
          | .captures | {(.[0].string): (.[1].string)}]
        | {payment_test: { service1: { api: add }}} ' tmp.txt
```

#### Using named capture variables

An improvement would be to use named capture variables. jq provides a filter, `capture`, for creating an object from the capture variables; it can be used in conjunction with `from_entries` like so:

```
[inputs | capture("\\[(?<key>.*)\\] (?<value>.*)")]
| from_entries
| {payment_test: { service1: { api: . }}}
```

Using such techniques, the string "payment_test_service1_api" could also be parsed, but the OP expectations regarding this are unclear, so maybe that's best left for another Q&A.

Answer (score 4):

Update: see [@peak's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40724176/1126841) for the generalization I couldn't quite get to.

---

This is far from the best solution, but demonstrates that it is possible to generate some JSON from arbitrary text.

```
jq -Rrn 'inputs | match("\\[(.*)\\] (.*)") | .captures[]|.string ' tmp.txt |
  jq -Rn '{
    payment_test: {
      service1: {
        api: {
          "\(input)": input,
          "\(input)": input,
          "\(input)": input
        }
      }
    }
  }
'
```

Here's a breakdown of each command:

1. The first one reads the input as raw text (`-R`), line-by-line inside the filter (`-n` along with the `inputs` function), and outputs raw text (`-r`) corresponding to the text in brackets and the rest of the line following the brackets.

   It is instructive to run the first command on your input one filter at a time to see how the full filter works. (That is, run each of the following in order:

   1. `jq -Rrn 'inputs' tmp.txt`
   2. `jq -Rrn 'inputs | match(...)' tmp.txt`
   3. `jq -Rrn 'inputs | match(...) | .captures' tmp.txt`
   4. `jq -Rrn 'inputs | match(...) | .captures[] | .string' tmp.txt`

   )
2. The second command simply reads each line, again as raw text and explicitly using `input`, and builds the desired object from each piece.

It should be possible to combine this into one call to `jq`; my skills at more complex commands are limited, but this demonstrates that you can cobble together a solution using simple pieces.

Answer (score 0):

The first parts of each line resembles the object structure in your results. If you could come up with a scheme to parse that out in an unambiguous way, you could treat them as paths to then set the values directly.

Assuming there are only three segments where only the first may contain underscores, you could do this:

```
$ jq -Rn 'reduce (inputs
        | [match("(\\S+)_([^_]+)_([^_]+)\\[([^\\]]+)\\] (\\S+)").captures[].string]
    ) as $p
    ({}; setpath($p[:-1]; $p[-1]))' input.txt
```